# Is it possible to ignore inline style with css?

Tags: html, css

```
<td class="subrubr" nowrap="nowrap" valign="bottom">
    <a name=""></a>
    Some long text to display here.
</td>
```

This line of code is being generated automatically by php and when it's a long text it breaks the design as it's trying to be all on one line(I don't have access to the generator I can just call the function that does it). I need to make it responsive with plain css and the nowrap attribute is what is causing me problems. Is there a way I can just ignore it or what is the best way or replacing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a specific selector to override the property

```css
td[nowrap="nowrap"] {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="subrubr" nowrap="nowrap" valign="bottom">
      <a name=""></a>
      Some long text to display here. Some long text to display here. Some long text to display here. Some long text to display here. Some long text to display here.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```